# MSI Action 'ISXmlAppSearch' is not permitted in a restricted engine

Tags: xml, windows-installer, installshield

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.  I have an InstallScript MSI project where I read values from an XML file via the "System Search" view.  When I upgrade an install with the exe, it completes, but fails to read the values of the XML file.  In the msi log, there is a line:

> Action 'ISXmlAppSearch' is not permitted in a restricted engine.

I have tried finding a solution, but there doesn't appear to be much information on this "restricted engine" issue at all.

Test is on Windows 7 PC, user account control is disabled (lowest setting on slider), and the installer .exe runs as administrator by default (though I tested it with "Run as Administrator" to be sure).  It fails 100% of the time with the same reason.

edit: It maybe appears that the [Installscript msi isn't running at elevated privileges](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/PROBLEM/Q112364)?

Comment: It's been too long since I ran across references to a restricted engine (I know something about the way InstallScript MSI runs does that). Do you see other references to `ISXmlAppSearch` that don't complain about the restricted engine? If so, it's more likely to be a problem with your search, such as bad XPath or a namespace issue.

Comment: I see both of my test versions have logged restricted engine errors for multiple InstallShield actions (ISSetupFilesExtract, DLLWrapStartup, ISXmlAppSearch, ISSQLServerInitialize, DLLWrapCleanup, and ISSetupFilesCleanup).  If I check the previous version of the installer from last year, there are no references to restricted engine at all.  Also, the XPath I use have worked in the past in the exact same context (minor upgrade).  I haven't changed them since.